# unable to send data to webservice through jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

> Hi there iam having trouble sending data to webservice through ajax
>   jquery.
>
> the onclient method fires but doesnt go to the service

here my aspx page code:

```
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Start() {
                debugger;
                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebService.asmx/Start",
                    data: '{speakstr: "' + $("#lbl").html() + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        // alert(msg.d);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl" Text="text" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="Btn" Text="listen" runat="server" OnClientClick="Start()" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

And here is my simple webservice.asmx page :

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static void Start(string text)
    {
        string txt = text;
    }
}
```

> Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
change code js code :

```
   function Start() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebService.asmx/Start",
                    data: JSON.stringify({"text" : $("#lbl").html()}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            }
```

and in the asmx, change the method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Start(string text)
{
    string txt = text;
    return txt; // just for test
}
```

Comment: the url could be wrong... 
url: "WebService.asmx/Start"
are you sure that the correct url ?
 i think can be something like this: 
 url: "http://localhost:8888/WebService.asmx/Start"

Comment: hi i tried ''function Start() {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "http://localhost:50417/WebService.asmx/Start",
                data:JSON.stringify({ "text": $("#lbl").html() }),
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
        }'' but not it didnt went to service.

Comment: do you have firebug? use firebug to see what happen with your post in console tab.

Comment: '[InvalidOperationException: No web service found at: /SpeechSite/WebService.asmx.]'

Comment: so, its that! you have to put the right 'url' parameter. try to access the web service with your browser.

Comment: Thanks it Worked there was a trouble in the asmx i made a new one and it worked.and changed the parameter names. Best Regards .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure but shouldn't your parameter name in your ajax call
be "text" also? Because that's what you're web method's parameter is.

Also, again I'm not too sure but shouldn't the [Webmethod] have parentheses after it?

Comment: Parenthesis aren't required in attributes.

Comment: wait a second, i think i've experienced this before. asp.net buttons tend to do postbacks even before the javascript attached to the clientclick hasn't completed. does the page refresh? can you try using a normal html <input type='button onclick='Start();' />?

Comment: Ive added "OnClientClick="Start();return false;" so i think the page wont refresh.